# Hiding a button inside a table view cell, iOS 7 / 6 difference

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with cells that each have a button, literally checkbox buttons.

After checking some boxes, there is another button outside the table view that does some processing on the data related to those cells. When that is done, what I always did for years was reload the table view data (`[tableview reloadData]`) so that the lines that had their buttons checked would have their check buttons hidden.

It always worked perfectly. The tableview cells would refresh accordingly. And they still do in the new app I'm making now, if I use iOS 6. But on iOS 7, the buttons that are supposed to change don't change. They only appear changed if I pop the controller with the table view and open that controller again.

EDIT >>>

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellSound%@", indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? @"0" : @"1"];
    Cellsound* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

then `cell.buttonCheck` is the property of the buttons. Later on I change visibility of the button like this:

```
cell.buttonCheck.hidden = {...}
```

Comment: can u please check whether the buttonCheck property  return the object or else nil

Comment: Yes I did check that while debugging. The property is the object, not nil.

Comment: I think a good rule of thumb is to use `[tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]` when contents of rows needs refreshing. I did, and suddenly I don't have any problem. I wonder why reloading the whole table didn't work, but then again this would probably be better for performance.

Comment: S off-course if u want to update the row based upon the content changes in data-source means its enough.